# Is it possible to give Evernote handwriting recognition?

Tags: scanning, evernote, handwriting-recognition

I have a lot of handwritten notes on my desk. I'd like to scan them in once a week and have the handwritten notes recognised and stored in Evernote, in order to have a full text search for all the notes.

I read that this is possible but cannot figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

If Evernote isn't the right tool to do this are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evernote does allow searching of text within images. Are you hoping it would provide a text version of the scanned images? I don't believe it does that. If you open the scanned image and search it for a word you should find it will highlight the word in the image itself.

Comment: You are right. I does find most of the things I'm looking for. Thanks for the answer.